# Laravel redirect or make view?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have made a contact form and I want to send the user to a thank you page or back to the contact form with an error message saying what fields were missing that need to be filled.

Initially I tried:

```
public function submit() {
    if (Input::has('name')) {
        $name = Input::get('name');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('apply')->with('message', 'Login Failed');
    }
    $this->thanks($name);
}

public function thanks() {
    return View::make('apply.thanks', array('metaTitle' => 'Application Sent | Thank you'));
}
```

But this gives me an error.

So I replaced the line `$this->thanks($name);` with `return Redirect::to('apply/thanks')->with('message', 'Login Failed');`

And it works.

My two questions are:

Is this the right way to send the user to the thank you page?

If there is an error, I would like to send back which errors occurred (what required fields weren't filled out). How is this achieved?

---

I have tried to implement route names:

routes file

```
Route::post('apply/submit', array('as' => 'applicationSubmit', 'uses' => 'ApplyController@submit'));
Route::post('apply/thanks', array('as' => 'applicationThanks', 'uses' => 'ApplyController@thanks'));
```

apply file

```
public function submit() {
    $validationErrors = array();
    if (Input::has('name')) {
        $name = Input::get('name');
    } else {
        $validationErrors[] = 'You must enter your name';
    }
    if($validationErrors) {
        if(Request::ajax()){

        } else {
            return Redirect::to('apply')->with('validationErrors', $validationErrors);
        }
    } else {
        if(Request::ajax()){

        } else {
            return Redirect::route('applicationThanks')->with('name', $name);
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm getting the error `Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException` (I found out how to turn the detailed error messages on :) )

Comment: "But this gives me an error" - do you mean a PHP error or a validation error? What error did you get?

Comment: `thanks` route is `GET` not `POST`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
public function submit() {
    if (Input::has('name')) {
        $name = Input::get('name');
    } else {
        return Redirect::to('apply')->with('message', 'Login Failed');
    }
    return Redirect::to('thanks')->with('name', $name);
}

public function thanks() {
    return View::make('apply.thanks', array('metaTitle' => 'Application Sent | Thank you'));
}
```

Of course you need to have defined route to `thanks`.

But you could also make it simpler without using `thanks` method at all:

```
public function submit() {
    if (Input::has('name')) {
        $name = Input::get('name');
        return View::make('apply.thanks', array('metaTitle' => 'Application Sent | Thank you'));
    }

    return Redirect::to('apply')->with('message', 'Login Failed');
}
```

I would rather go for second method (there's no need to make extra redirection just to display view).

You could also consider using [named routes](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes) in case you will change your urls in future

**EDIT**

Route for `thanks` need to use get method and not post because you make redirection to it (no form data are sent by user to this route), so instead of:

```
Route::post('apply/thanks', array('as' => 'applicationThanks', 'uses' => 'ApplyController@thanks'));
```

it should be rather:

```
Route::get('apply/thanks', array('as' => 'applicationThanks', 'uses' => 'ApplyController@thanks'));
```

I advise you to look at [Basic routing](http://laravel.com/docs/routing#basic-routing) - you should really understand verbs and routing and in case you don't care you can always use `Route::any` to match all verbs: POST, GET, PUT, PATCH and DELETE - but in my opinion it's better to use correct verb and not all of them.

Comment: `Redirect::to()` is for url, `Redirect::route()` is for named routes.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk That's what I mean - he should consider naming his routes and using `Redirect::route()` instead of `Redirect::to()`